# Support Function Notation

Tags: equations, matrices

How can I write an equation having the following term in LaTeX:
[image]

The hard part for me is to align the W in the right hand side.

Comment: ?The W should be aligned in which way, exactly?

Comment: @Bernard It should be on the same baseline as `-\delta^*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both a friendly syntax and varying size for inline and displayed formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\support}[1]{\aslv@support#1\@nil}
\def\aslv@support#1\\#2|#3\@nil{%
  \mleft(
  \genfrac..{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}
  \mskip\aslv@supportskip
  \middle|
  \mskip\aslv@supportskip
  #3
  \mright)
}
\newmuskip\aslv@supportskip
\aslv@supportskip=4mu % <--- adjust to suit
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We have the formula in line $\delta^+\support{1+d^Tr \\ V^Td+b(x) | W}$
or displayed
\[
\delta^+\support{1+d^Tr \\ V^Td+b(x) | W}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A quite elegant code!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. I list two below, the first using a `pmatrix` (from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) and the other using regular `\left`/`\right` extensible parentheses (you can also use `\mleft`/`\mright` from [`mleftright`](//ctan.org/pkg/mleftright)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\begin{document}

% Uses amsmath
\[
  a \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{} c | @{\hspace{\arraycolsep}}}
      b \\
      c
    \end{array}
    d
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

% Uses mleftright, but can also just use \left/\right instead of \mleft/\mright
\[
  a \mleft(
    \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      b \\
      c
    \end{array}
    \middle\vert
    d
  \mright)
\]

\end{document}
```

Both include an `array` for the split of `b` and `c` vertically centred with respect to `a` and `d`. The one uses `\middle\vert` to set the vertical rule, while the other uses the array vertical rule. You can intermix these.

Comment: Variation: Instead of `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}..\end{array}`, package `amsmath` provides `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`.

Answer (score 2):

Two other variants, with `delarray` or `blkarray` and `\multirowcell` from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, delarray, multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\[
  -\delta^{*}\! \begin{array}({@{}c|c@{}})
1 + d^{\top}\tau & \multirowcell{2}{W} \\
V^{\top} d + b(x){}
\end{array}
\]

\[
   \begin{blockarray}{c(c|c)}
\BAmultirow{1em}{$ -\delta^{*} $} & 1 + d^{\top}\tau & \BAmultirow{1em}{$ W $} \\
& V^{\top} d + b(x){}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]